# How does Python handle non-printable characters?

Tags: python, encryption, character, ascii

I'm making a program that encrypts a file using keys.
It can encrypt only numbers, letters, spaces, some symbols.
Etc.

```
This is text >>> h5D#I2%%&12s
```

My program can encrypt a file, too. (At least I'm working on it)
What if file contains characters like this ? - uún‰3«°Ø and also NULL, CAN or SOH characters.

I have an idea: I want to leave these and all other non-ascii characters unencrypted. But I don't know if Python can work with them.

P.S. Here is link to the project: (And It's unfinished, not working)
https://www.dropbox.com/sh/lq8j4vmci5c2vmh/AADeSTPVYeV13z5HRHp-NlWPa?dl=0

Comment: Python byte strings are just that; bytes. They can handle all possible byte values from 0 to 255. Opn your files in binary mode to prevent the OS from translating newline characters and you should be just fine.

Comment: Ok, thx does this mean i can to this: string = (some non-printable characters) file.write(string)

Comment: Yes, otherwise Python could not handle any binary data, like images or indeed encryption.

Comment: non-printable just means byte values that do not map to a printable character in the ASCII table. That doesn't mean the data is actually ASCII text.

Comment: That means I can read line from a file and than use find on every character and if i can't find character in a list of all known characters (if I get -1) i can leave that character unencrypted ? You can post this as answer, too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Python byte strings (type `str` in Python 2, `bytes` in Python 3) are just opaque sequences of bytes, where each byte has an integer value between 0 and 255.

How you treat those bytes is up to you. You could treat them as text; printing the text, splitting on whitespace, changing case, etc. Or you can just treat it as binary data, your choice. If you chose to treat the contents as text, then yes, some bytes are 'unprintable' because the ASCII codec hasn't assigned a printable glyph to those codepoints. Python, however, doesn't care.

Open your files in binary mode (`'rb'`, `'wb'`, etc.) to make sure that line separators (`\n`, or `\r` or `\r\n` characters) are not translated from and to the platform native form.